# "Litus Saxonicum", or "Litus Saxonicus"

Tags: classical-latin

Well  I have found the Saxon Shore written, in some sites, as "Litus Saxonicus", It seems OK, but I have found as well Litus Saxonicum. Source: Notitia dignitatum.

Answer (score 8):

lītus, gen. lītŏris “shore” is definitely neuter. Litus saxonicus is thus wrong (unless you mean lĭtus, gen. -ūs “smearing”, which is masculine).

Comment: This answer could be improved: If "saxonicus" is wrong, does that mean "saxonicum" is right?

Comment: @Quuxplusone. Correct.

Comment: Yes, this answer could be clearer. After all, not all neuter adjectives end in *-um* either (e.g. *litus Cantiense*), but *Saxonicus, -a, -um* does indeed.